# How to set viewport height auto in CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to capture screenshot of multiple web page, each having varying heights. How can I set height dynamically based on the page height?

Something like this:
`casper.viewport(1200, 'auto');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CasperJS screenshot is only a small part of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156452/casperjs-screenshot-is-only-a-small-part-of-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default PhantomjS browser (which is used by CasperJS) renders **full height of the page automatically**. In CasperJS the corresponding method is

```
casper.capture()
```

To set the horizontal width of the page, set viewport size:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {width: 1280, height: 800}
});
```

This setting will only affect the **width** of the screenshot, the **height** will be as big as necessary to render the whole page.

Example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
    }
});
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};

casper.start("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phantomjs");
casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture("stackoverflow.png");
});

casper.run();
```

[The resulting image (439 kb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqOzz.png) is 3448 pixels high which is way more than 1024 pixels set in options.

Comment: I would like to set the width fix size but not the height. In the second example you have defined fixed height of '800' which is not what I need. The height should be automatically set based on the page height.

Comment: Sorry didn't get my point through to you first time, please check out the revised answer, hope it will help. **summary: the height option in config will be ignored, the screenshot will be of full page height**.